# Too many watchable $scope variables and f'unctions result in RangeError

Tags: angularjs, range

When I kept on adding $scope variables and functions, all of a sudden, I now see *"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"*. The JS file is valid and does not have errors. Is there a way to get rid of this? Or, can I increase the the amount of watchable variables/functions?
[image]

$scope.calculator:

```
"totalpay": function(){
    var total = 0.00;
    total += parseFloat($scope.fields.totalrate.value);
    total += parseFloat($scope.fields.totalovertime.value);
    total += parseFloat($scope.calculator.totalvacation());
    total += parseFloat($scope.calculator.totalholiday());
    total += parseFloat($scope.calculator.totalsickleave());
    $scope.fields.totalpay.value = total;
    return total;
},
```

Comment: Can you post your code?  Angular can handle thousands of bindings so you've probably done something that needs debugging (even if valid JS).

Comment: I see that you posted code, but it's not enough.  We don't know what any of the total functions are doing or where your `fields` or `calculator` models are defined.  It would be best if you could post everything that's relevant to your question, preferably in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).